# How to store the numbers of a button click in an integer

Tags: objective-c, count

so my question sounds stupid but I am new at this and I am trying to code My first app alone , wich basically should count the number of stairs i walked . I have 20 stairs so in the app whenever I press the button the result should be changed depending on the amounts of clicks . So my only question is how to count the amount of clicks on a button .
Thanks ,
Oh and excuse my english , i am french .

Comment: You need to create a variable and wire up the touch up inside event of the UIButton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare an integer and increment it by 1 each time in the result button method.

like this

```
- (IBAction)resultButton:(id)sender 
{
//all your code
yourInteger++
}
```

Comment: The text of a button is not readonly. It can easily be changed.

Comment: my bad. How do you change it?

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to store the clicks-count in a local variable. Every time the button get pressed, you have to increase the value of the counter by 1.

A little code example would looks like:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger counter;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.counter = 0;
    [self.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    self.counter++;

    self.myButton.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Stairs walked: %i", self.counter];
}

@end
```